# Is it illegal for a parent to refuse to pay medical expenses with child support in the USA?

Tags: health, health-insurance, children

I am asking one a friend's behalf.

My friend's parents are divorced, my friend (18, F) is living with her mother and her mother's boyfriend (not married to each other). The mother receives child support however refuses to pay for health insurance. My friend is left without medical coverage, has not been to a doctor for a routine checkup in two years and has not been to a dentist for six years. She is worried about the state of her teeth, but as mentioned she does not have the finances to visit a dentist.

Is it illegal for the mother to refuse to cover the child's health needs?

Comment: The child is an adult, is she not?

Comment: @phoog Yes, she is. Does that make is so that she has to cover her own medical expenses?

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid.  I suspect she would have had a better case before her 18th birthday, but if the child support is still due to be paid to her mother on her behalf, her age may not yet be a problem.  With any luck someone who knows more about family law will answer.  The jurisdiction will probably be relevant.  What state is she in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The mother is not obligated because the child is 18. And has, therefore, reached the ***age of majority*** in New Hampshire. (See below chart.)

**Before** age of majority:

- Parents are legally obligated to provide for the basic wellbeing of the child including but not limited to proper medical care.

**After** age of majority:

- Parents do not have any legal or financial obligation for the care and maintenance of children.
- Parents should not be paying or receiving child support payments.

#### Exception to Statutory Obligations

It is possible, however, that the parenting plan or custody agreement places extra-statutory obligations on one or both parents while child support is being paid. It would be important to read the parenting plan or custody agreement to see if that sets forth obligations for the mother not covered by statute. In which case the child could sue the mom for contempt of court or violation of the custody agreement (or whatever it might be called in New Hampshire) in order to enforce it.

#### Age of Majority by U.S. State

[Source](http://contests.about.com/od/3/g/ageofmajority.htm): http://contests.about.com/od/3/g/ageofmajority.htm

State   Age of Majority

Alabama 19

Alaska  18

Arizona 18

Arkansas    18 or graduation from high school, whichever is later

California  18

Colorado    18

Connecticut 18

Delaware    19

District of Columbia    18

Florida 18

Georgia 18

Hawaii  18

Idaho   18

Illinois    18

Indiana 18

Iowa    18

Kansas  18

Kentucky    18

Louisiana   18

Maine   18

Maryland    18

Massachusetts   18

Michigan    18

Minnesota   18

Missouri    18

Mississippi 21

Montana 18

Nebraska    19

New Hampshire   18

New Mexico  18

Nevada  18, or if still in high school at 18, 19 or graduation, whichever comes sooner

New Jersy   18

New York    18

North Carolina  18

North Dakota    18

Ohio    18 or graduation from high school, whichever comes first

Oklahoma    18

Oregon  18

Pennsylvania    18

Rhode Island    18

South Carolina  18

South Dakota    18

Tennessee   18 or graduation from high school, whichever is later

Texas   18

Utah    18 or graduation from high school, whichever is earlier

Vermont 18

Virginia    18

Washington  18

West Virginia   18

Wisconsin   18, or if still in high school at 18, 19 or graduation, whichever comes sooner

Wyoming 18

Comment: I should have specified which state she is living in. She is living in New Hampshire, and she is not graduated from high school yet so child support is still paid. I hope that I am correct to assume that the same obligations before 18 still apply since child support is still in effect? Very helpful, though.

Comment: @cakeisajoke: Read edited version. There is still a chance. +1